# converting multi array object to json string in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to convert this object to json string but the result is not returning the object for address.

here's the code

```
{
        name: $('[name="name"]').val(),
        age: $('[name="age"]').val(),
        sex: $('[name="sex"]').val(),
        birthday: $('[name="birthday"]').val(),
        about: $('[name="about"]').val(),
        addresses: mapAlfredObject(getAlfredObject('addresses')),
        contacts: mapAlfredObject(getAlfredObject('contacts')),
    };
```

here's how I implemented the mapAlfredObject method

```
function mapAlfredObject(obj) {
    var items = [];
    for (var index in obj) {
        items[obj[index]['name']] = {
            value: obj[index]['value'],
            type: obj[index]['type'],
            comment: obj[index]['comment']
        };
    }
    return items;
}
```

here's the log from console

[image]

and the output from JSON.stringify

```
{"name":"","age":"","sex":"","birthday":"any","about":"","addresses":[],"contacts":[]}
```

Comment: please add the object in text form.

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in snippet or fiddle?

Comment: `var items = [];` or `var items = {};`

Comment: @PranavCBalan it worked by using var items = {}; 
thanks!

Comment: Could't you use the jQuery method `.serializeArray` ?